# I want to run a function on an element in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can not to run a function on an element in an array in JavaScript. In the code below, I want another function to run when the structure "2" is left to the text "two".I tried working on `cardNumber` and `slotNumber`, but it worked on all elements, not the element I specified. What can I do? There was no build attempt on `slodNumber`.

```js
var correctCards = 0;
$(init);

function init() {

  // Hide the success message
  $('#successMessage').hide();
  $('#successMessage').css({
    left: '580px',
    top: '250px',
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  });

  // Reset the game
  correctCards = 0;
  $('#cardPile').html('');
  $('#cardSlots').html('');

  // Create the pile of shuffled cards
  var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  var terms = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];


  //numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $('<div>' + terms[i] + '</div>').data('number', numbers[i]).attr('id', 'card' + numbers[i]).appendTo('#cardPile').draggable({
      stack: '#cardPile div',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    });
  }

  // Create the card slots
  var words = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
  for (var j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
    $('<div>' + words[j - 1] + '</div>').data('number', j).appendTo('#cardSlots').droppable({
      accept: '#cardPile div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleCardDrop
    });
  }
}

function handleCardDrop(event, ui) {
  var slotNumber = $(this).data('number');
  var cardNumber = ui.draggable.data('number');



  // If the card was dropped to the correct slot,
  // change the card colour, position it directly
  // on top of the slot, and prevent it being dragged
  // again

  if (slotNumber == cardNumber) {

    // ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    // $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this),
      my: 'left top',
      at: 'left top'
    }); //bu değil
    ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
    correctCards++;
  }

  // If all the cards have been placed correctly then display a message
  // and reset the cards for another go

  if (correctCards == 5) {
    $('#successMessage').show();
    $('#successMessage').animate({
      left: '380px',
      top: '200px',
      width: '400px',
      height: '100px',
      opacity: 1
    });
  }

}
```

```css
#content {
  margin: 80px 70px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#cardSlots {
  margin: 0 auto 3em auto;
  background: navy;
  float: right;
}


/* The initial pile of unsorted cards */

#cardPile {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: green;
  float: left;
}

#cardSlots,
#cardPile {
  width: 47%;
  height: 80%;
  padding: .85em;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 .3em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 .3em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 .3em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}


/* Individual cards and slots */

#cardSlots div,
#cardPile div {
  float: left;
  width: 43%;
  height: 18%;
  padding: .85em;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  background: #fff;
}


/*#cardSlots div:first-child, #cardPile div:first-child {
        margin-left: 0;
        }*/

#cardSlots div.hovered {
  background: #aaa;
}

#cardSlots div {
  border-style: dashed;
}

#cardPile div {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
  text-align: center;
}

#cardPile div.ui-draggable-dragging {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

#successMessage {
  position: absolute;
  left: 580px;
  top: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #dfd;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: .3em .3em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: .3em .3em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: .3em .3em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="surukle.css">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
  <hr>
  <div class="anayapi">
    <div id="deneme" class="sag" onload="startGame()">
    </div>
    <div class="sol">
      <div id="content">
        <div id="cardPile"> </div>
        <div id="cardSlots"> </div>
        <div id="successMessage">
          <h2>Congratulations!</h2>
          <button onclick="init()">Play Again</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, your question is cluttered with a lot of code, most of it probably not related to the issue. Have you considered creating a [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example]? This will first of all help yourself debugging the code, and would also help other people who want to help you.

Comment: What I wanted to ask was how can I run another function when we actually call an element of an array. This is the whole project I'm dealing with. I don't have a chance to minimize the project. It says page not found.

Comment: Sorry, I read both your question and your last comment, and I cannot understand the sentences. Try reorganizing your thoughts about the situation and explain what you are trying to do, to someone who is not involved in your project.

Comment: Could rephrase this - when the structure "2" is left to the text "two" - because it isn't making sense to me.